# How to reduce bundle.js / main.[hash].js size in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build, npm-build

n my react app, when I run npm run build then lot of chunk files are created and also one **main.[hash].js** file
and that **main.[hash].js** file size is ~138kb (attached screenshots below for reference)
[image]

Due to this performance of my app is getting low as per *PageSpeed* test or *LightHouse* test (attached screenshots below for reference) and its in Reduced unused Javascript
And in react app there's no such code which are unused

[image]

So how to reduce size of main.[hash].js file so that performance will increase ?

In this app I did not eject web-pack files so there no config file in this app
also I have already use code splitting technique like *lazy/suspence* in all routes.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you click on Learn More? Did you view the script in the Treemap viewer to discover possible unused code?

Comment: @ConnorClark I had tried it. I have already used lazy loading in landing page as well as all routes but still not effect on main.js